# access and refresh a directive from another

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a page wich is composed by 2 directives :
PeopleHeader 
PeopleAction

I do some treatments in the peopleAction directive
When these treatments end , i want update a variable in the header directive and refresh the header
Any helps would be appreciated
Thank you very much

Header directive

```
app.directive("peopleHeader", [
        "ListeCmcQueryHelper", function(ListeQueryHelper) {
            return {
                templateUrl : "partials/people/peopleHeader.html",
                restrict : "E",
                link : function(scope) {

                    scope.nbPeople= ListeQueryHelper.totalRequested; // how to refresh this variable and so the view from PeopleActionDirective

                }
            };
        }
]);
```

Html associated to headerDirective

```
<h3> {{'PEOPLE.TITLE' | translate}} </h3>
<h5> {{'PEOPLE.TOTAL' | translate }} : {{nbPeople.total}}</h5>
```

PeopleActionDirective

```
      app.directive("peopleAction", [
                "ListeQueryHelper", function(ListeQueryHelper) {
                    return {
                        templateUrl : "partials/people/peopleAction.html",
                        restrict : "E",
                        link : function(scope) {

                             scope.deletePeople= function() {
                             ListeQueryHelper.deletePeople();
                             scope.nbPeople= ListeQueryHelper.totalRequested;
                            // need to send this to HeaderDirective and so refresh the view
                          }

                        }
                    };
                }
        ]);
```

Thank you very much

Comment: is `ListeQueryHelper.totalRequested` getting changed? If so it should already be updated in other directive unless the change is being performed by code outside of angular.

Comment: is 'ListeQueryHelper.totalRequested' an Object ?

Comment: @charlietfl , yeah it will be changed a lot by a rest services( back end side)

Comment: @maxisam , no just a integer

Comment: show the asynch code, it may need to call apply if it's not angular code doing the update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, link function only run once. So in you example code, it will only get the value from  `ListeQueryHelper.totalRequested` once.

Solution 1:
Do it in [two way binding](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.27/docs/guide/directive#isolating-the-scope-of-a-directive) by using '=' 
Btw, you need to be familiar with Directive if you go with Solution 1. Read that link first.

Solution 2:
Use object instead. `scope.nbPeople=ListeQueryHelper.SomeObj`
and in the html : `nbPeople.totalRequested`

Solution 3:
Use event.

Comment: Thank you very much , the two way bindings is the more elegant solution . It works great now :)

Answer (score 1):

`ListeQueryHelper` is a service, right?
If it's not then make it one.

So in both your directives `scope.nbPeople` have the same reference: `ListeQueryHelper.totalRequested`.

Changing it in one of them will reflect in the other. Thus if you call `scope.deletePeople` in an `ng-click` for example (that automatically calls `scope.$apply` for you) you will be able to `scope.$watch('nbPeople', ...` in the other directive.
Or just bind it to the template (`<span>{{nbPeople}}</span>`).

Comment: Thank you for your answer , it's the same reference indeed , but the  ListeQueryHelper.totalRequested call a asynchronous method for update the variable so the changes isn't reflected (until i reload manually the page of course). I tried the $watch example and it didn't work :(

Comment: So `ListeQueryHelper.totalRequested` is a function? Then you need to assign the result to a _property_ on `ListeQueryHelper`.

Comment: Thank you very much , this solution works too but i prefer the two way bindings

Comment: Of course you need a two way binding. I guessed you already did that :)